# In the 2-cell collection view, the 2nd cell return with different numbers but always shows the same data. how do i fix it?

Tags: swift, storyboard, collectionview

In the 2-cell collection view, cell 1 always rotates once and cell 2 rotates different numbers. . There are 12 labels in cell 2. The labels in the rows of cell 2 are different among themselves but the same in each row. For example, the 1st cell rotated 1 time, the 2nd cell rotated 7 times. 7 lines are the same. I want all 7 rows to receive the next data.

Data comes from 2 different data in the setup Country Header Cell and this works properly because it rotates once, but setupClublineCell one rotates sometimes 8, sometimes 7, sometimes 4. The return numbers are correct but it always returns the same data.

Some of my codes are like this. Thank you in advance for your help and interest.

```
var grups = [[String]]()
var grupsCO = [[String]]()
var grupsCL = [[String]]()


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "title", for: indexPath) as! CountryHeaderCell
        setupCountryHeaderCell(cell: cell, section: indexPath.section)
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "titleclub", for: indexPath) as! ClublineCell
        setupClublineCell(cell: cell, section: indexPath.section)
        return cell
    }
}

func setupCountryHeaderCell(cell: CountryHeaderCell, section: Int) {
    if section < grups.count {
        let grup = grups[section]
        let grupCO = grupsCO[section]

        for i in 0..<11 {
            let label = cell.value(forKey: "labelH\(i + 1)") as! UILabel
            label.text = (i < grup.count) ? grup[i] : ""
        }

        for k in 0..<12 {
            let labelCO = cell.value(forKey: "labelCO\(k + 1)") as! UILabel
            labelCO.text = (k < grupCO.count) ? grupCO[k] : ""
        }
    }
}

func setupClublineCell(cell: ClublineCell, section: Int) {
            for j in 0..<12 {
                let labelCL = cell.value(forKey: "labelCL\(j + 1)") as? UILabel
                labelCL?.text = (j < grupsCL[section].count) ? grupsCL[section][j] : ""
            }
}
```